# MySQL Database can't find the table after file dump

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, laragon

I am trying to download and view a MySQL database in phpmyadmin hosted on Laragon. So, I downloaded the files and placed them into a new file in the database folder:

[image]

I then loaded phpmyadmin and saw that the database and its entire structure were displayed:

[image]

However, when I try and view the table `students` to see the data, I get the error message `#1146 - Table 'students2.students' doesn't exist`.